# Multiple autocomplete mat-chip-grid with Angular 15

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, angular15, angular17

I'm looking for an angular 15 compatible example of using multiple mat-chip-grid.  I've seen it done with mat-chip-lists in Angular 8https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gjwo4-rfudwx?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.ts.  I'm looking to use the newer mat-chip-grid.

Going off the autocomplete/chip example on the angular site(https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chips-autocomplete), when I add an additional mat-chip-grids it looks like it breaks the form.

Has anyone done this before?

I just want to change the autocomplete/chip example to have 2 drop-down lists instead of 1, like a list for favorite fruits and a list for least favorite fruits.

This is the example I'm currently working on: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bzg111-ocagew?file=src%2Fexample%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts